# access object in array with blanc key in json typescript

Tags: arrays, json, typescript

I am using storage connector in loopback to load files onto the file system. for every loaded file I am receiving a response like:

```
{
    "files": {
        "": [
            {
                "container": "00003",
                "name": "mydoc.docx",
                "type": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
                "field": "",
                "size": 23384
            }
        ]
    },
    "fields": {}
}
```

There an issue with the returned array with a key "".  The objected containing the above is called loadedFile, say I would like to print the size of the loaded file.
console.log(obj.files.""[0].size);

The above doesn't work as the array doesn't have a name in the response.

Please, can anyone point out to a solution?

Thanks in advance and Regards

T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the property via the [*Bracket notation*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#bracket_notation), rather than the [*Dot notation*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#dot_notation).

In your case:

```js
console.log(obj.files[""][0].size)
```

Comment: Many Thanks for your answer, it perfectly works!, Best. T

Comment: Glad to hear it works for you! If I helped you, it would be kind if you could accept my answer (The checkmark next to my answer). Thanks!